# How to save the reports to a directory using SSRS with Azure

Tags: azure, reporting-services, azure-sql-database

How to save the reports to a directory using SSRS with Azure?

[image: saving reports to directory]

Comment: "How to save the reports to a directory using SSRS with Azure." is a web search you can try. Unfortunately, this is not on-topic for this site.

Comment: Like I said in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110658/how-can-bot-receives-a-notification-from-ssrs use a subscription. This is your third question on basically the same topic. I suggest you install SSRS and do some experimenting and reading.

Comment: "With Azure" is a very broad statement which suggests you're not too sure what you're asking. Also as I said in my other question, you have a complicated process for something that probably mostly already exists in SSRS under subscriptions. Go and experiment with SSRS and subscriptions.

Comment: Oh wait I see the problem. Your SSRS database is too squishy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need an Azure VM (IaaS) where you can install a SQL Server instance and install SQL Server Reporting Services. On that Azure VM you can save your reports. You can also save your reports on an on-premise SQL Server.

Once created the Azure VM with SSRS installed you can create reports that connect to Azure SQL Database databases as source of data.

SQL Server Reporting Services is not part of Azure SQL Database (PaaS) and is not available as SaaS in Azure either. It is only available as (IaaS).